# how to write the word "so as if it is slurred or exagerated

Tags: technique, dialogue, word-choice

How should I write the word "so" as if it is slurred or exaggerated
for example:
I'm sooo sorry. I've been so miserable and lonely.

Comment: I'd Shuggesht "Sho" and shee if that shlurred shpeech enough.

Comment: Alternatively, see the following: https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/44528/34330

Comment: Maybe italicize it?